# Multiple-choice results message - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

When a user selects any combination of answers (even both **correct answers**), on the multiple-choice questions and presses the "Get Results" button, they will get the message: "You got 0 out of 2 (0%) correct."  I can't seem to find the error in the code. Any help is appreciated, thx :-)

HTML Code

```
<div class="outer-container">
<p id="title"></p>
<p id="bodytext"></p>
<p id="source"></p>
<div id="quiz"></div>
<button id="submit">Get Results</button>
<p id="results"></p>
<button id="generate">Generate</button>
</div>
```

JavaScript Code

```
// Define variables
      let title = document.getElementById("title");
      let bodytext = document.getElementById("bodytext");
      let source = document.getElementById("source");
      let quiz = document.getElementById("quiz");
      let submitButton = document.getElementById("submit");
      let results = document.getElementById("results");
      let generateButton = document.getElementById("generate");

// Define sample data
      let sampleData = [
        {
          title: "Sample Title 1",
          bodytext: "This is the first sample text.",
          source: "Source 1",
          quiz: [
            {
              question: "What is the capital of France?",
              choices: ["New York", "Paris", "London", "Berlin"],
              answer: "Paris"
            },
            {
              question: "What is the largest country in the world?",
              choices: ["Russia", "China", "India", "USA"],
              answer: "Russia"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          title: "Sample Title 2",
          bodytext: "This is the second sample text.",
          source: "Source 2",
          quiz: [
            {
              question: "What is the largest planet in our solar system?",
              choices: ["Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Venus"],
              answer: "Jupiter"
            },
            {
              question: "What is the highest mountain in the world?",
              choices: ["Mount Everest", "K2", "Kangchenjunga", "Lhotse"],
              answer: "Mount Everest"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          title: "Sample Title 3",
          bodytext: "This is the third sample text.",
          source: "Source 3",
          quiz: [
            {
              question: "How many colors are on the Spanish flag?",
              choices: ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"],
              answer: "Three"
            },
            {
              question: "What is the smallest planet in our solar system?",
              choices: ["Mercury", "Venus", "Mars", "Earth"],
              answer: "Mercury"
            }
          ]
        }
      ];

// Define event listeners
      generateButton.addEventListener("click", generateContent);
      submitButton.addEventListener("click", checkAnswer);

// Initialize current index
      let currentIndex = 0;
      let currentQuizIndex = 0;

// Function to generate content
      function generateContent() {
        // Get the data object at the current index in the sample data array
        let data = sampleData[currentIndex];
        let quizData = data.quiz[currentQuizIndex];

// Update the DOM with the data
        title.textContent = data.title;
        bodytext.textContent = data.bodytext;
        source.textContent = "Source: " + data.source;

// Generate the quiz HTML
        let quizHTML = "";
for (let i = 0; i < data.quiz.length; i++) {
quizHTML += "<p>" + data.quiz[i].question + "</p>";
for (let j = 0; j < data.quiz[i].choices.length; j++) {
quizHTML += "<label><input type='radio' name='answer" + i + "' value='" + data.quiz[i].choices[j] + "'> " + data.quiz[i].choices[j] + "</label><br>";
}
}
quiz.innerHTML = quizHTML;

// Clear the results
results.textContent = "";

// Increment the current index
currentIndex++;

// Reset the current index to 0 if we reach the end of the array
if (currentIndex >= sampleData.length) {
currentIndex = 0;
}
}

// Function to check the answer
function checkAnswer() {
  let selectedAnswers = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < sampleData[currentIndex].quiz.length; i++) {
    let selectedAnswer = document.querySelector("input[name='answer" + i + "']:checked");
    if (selectedAnswer === null) {
      results.textContent = "Please answer all questions.";
      return;
    }
    selectedAnswers.push(selectedAnswer.value.trim().toLowerCase()); // add .trim().toLowerCase() here
  }

  let correctAnswers = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < sampleData[currentIndex].quiz.length; i++) {
    correctAnswers.push(sampleData[currentIndex].quiz[i].answer.trim().toLowerCase()); // add .trim().toLowerCase() here
  }

  if (selectedAnswers.length !== correctAnswers.length) {
    results.textContent = "Please answer all questions.";
    return;
  }

  let numCorrect = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < selectedAnswers.length; i++) {
    if (selectedAnswers[i] === correctAnswers[i]) {
      numCorrect++;
    }
  }

  let percentCorrect = (numCorrect / selectedAnswers.length) * 100;
  results.textContent = "You got " + numCorrect + " out of " + selectedAnswers.length + " (" + percentCorrect.toFixed(2) + "%)";
}


// Call the generateContent() function when the page loads
generateContent();
```

Comment: After your loop to assign correctAnswers, add some debugging: `console.log(correctAnswers)` - the correctAnswers array doesn't match the *asked* questions.

Comment: You increment the current index after generating the question html but before checking the question.

Comment: It appears: each time you ask a question, you increase `currentIndex`,  but when you get the correct answers, you use the *current* `currentIndex` which has now been increased to the *next* two questions.   You need to either use a different variable or reset `currentIndex` back to what it was - you'll also need the loop-back-to-start code that you have when asking questions (not just a simple `for`)

Comment: I think a quick fix might be to move `currentIndex++` to the top of `generateContent` and start `currentIndex` at -1;

Comment: An alternative would be to have `questionIndex = []` and `questionIndex.push(currentIndex)` when you ask a question, then a simple loop of questionIndex values to get the asked questions.   This would also allow you to change how you ask questions (to be random rather than sequential) without a change to how they are checked.

Comment: If you do do what I suggested I think you'd also need to move `if (currentIndex >= sampleData.length) { currentIndex = 0; }` to the top of `generateContent` (but still after `currentIndex++`).

Comment: @BenStephens thanks, that did work, but now the "Generate" button has stopped working.

Comment: @rivvie99 I've added my comments as an answer. It seems to be working, are there particular conditions necessary to stop the Generate button working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You increment the current index after generating the question html but before checking the question. I think a quick fix might be to move `currentIndex++` to the top of `generateContent` and start `currentIndex` at -1; I think you'd also need to move `if (currentIndex >= sampleData.length) { currentIndex = 0; }` to the top of `generateContent` (but still after `currentIndex++`).

```js
// Define variables
      let title = document.getElementById("title");
      let bodytext = document.getElementById("bodytext");
      let source = document.getElementById("source");
      let quiz = document.getElementById("quiz");
      let submitButton = document.getElementById("submit");
      let results = document.getElementById("results");
      let generateButton = document.getElementById("generate");

// Define sample data
      let sampleData = [
        {
          title: "Sample Title 1",
          bodytext: "This is the first sample text.",
          source: "Source 1",
          quiz: [
            {
              question: "What is the capital of France?",
              choices: ["New York", "Paris", "London", "Berlin"],
              answer: "Paris"
            },
            {
              question: "What is the largest country in the world?",
              choices: ["Russia", "China", "India", "USA"],
              answer: "Russia"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          title: "Sample Title 2",
          bodytext: "This is the second sample text.",
          source: "Source 2",
          quiz: [
            {
              question: "What is the largest planet in our solar system?",
              choices: ["Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Venus"],
              answer: "Jupiter"
            },
            {
              question: "What is the highest mountain in the world?",
              choices: ["Mount Everest", "K2", "Kangchenjunga", "Lhotse"],
              answer: "Mount Everest"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          title: "Sample Title 3",
          bodytext: "This is the third sample text.",
          source: "Source 3",
          quiz: [
            {
              question: "How many colors are on the Spanish flag?",
              choices: ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"],
              answer: "Three"
            },
            {
              question: "What is the smallest planet in our solar system?",
              choices: ["Mercury", "Venus", "Mars", "Earth"],
              answer: "Mercury"
            }
          ]
        }
      ];

// Define event listeners
      generateButton.addEventListener("click", generateContent);
      submitButton.addEventListener("click", checkAnswer);

// Initialize current index
      let currentIndex = -1;
      let currentQuizIndex = 0;

// Function to generate content
      function generateContent() {
        // Increment the current index
        currentIndex++;

        // Reset the current index to 0 if we reach the end of the array
        if (currentIndex >= sampleData.length) {
          currentIndex = 0;
        }
        // Get the data object at the current index in the sample data array
        let data = sampleData[currentIndex];
        let quizData = data.quiz[currentQuizIndex];

// Update the DOM with the data
        title.textContent = data.title;
        bodytext.textContent = data.bodytext;
        source.textContent = "Source: " + data.source;

// Generate the quiz HTML
        let quizHTML = "";
for (let i = 0; i < data.quiz.length; i++) {
quizHTML += "<p>" + data.quiz[i].question + "</p>";
for (let j = 0; j < data.quiz[i].choices.length; j++) {
quizHTML += "<label><input type='radio' name='answer" + i + "' value='" + data.quiz[i].choices[j] + "'> " + data.quiz[i].choices[j] + "</label><br>";
}
}
quiz.innerHTML = quizHTML;

// Clear the results
results.textContent = "";


}

// Function to check the answer
function checkAnswer() {
  let selectedAnswers = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < sampleData[currentIndex].quiz.length; i++) {
    let selectedAnswer = document.querySelector("input[name='answer" + i + "']:checked");
    if (selectedAnswer === null) {
      results.textContent = "Please answer all questions.";
      return;
    }
    selectedAnswers.push(selectedAnswer.value.trim().toLowerCase()); // add .trim().toLowerCase() here
  }

  let correctAnswers = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < sampleData[currentIndex].quiz.length; i++) {
    correctAnswers.push(sampleData[currentIndex].quiz[i].answer.trim().toLowerCase()); // add .trim().toLowerCase() here
  }

  if (selectedAnswers.length !== correctAnswers.length) {
    results.textContent = "Please answer all questions.";
    return;
  }

  let numCorrect = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < selectedAnswers.length; i++) {
    if (selectedAnswers[i] === correctAnswers[i]) {
      numCorrect++;
    }
  }

  let percentCorrect = (numCorrect / selectedAnswers.length) * 100;
  results.textContent = "You got " + numCorrect + " out of " + selectedAnswers.length + " (" + percentCorrect.toFixed(2) + "%)";
}


// Call the generateContent() function when the page loads
generateContent();
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
<p id="title"></p>
<p id="bodytext"></p>
<p id="source"></p>
<div id="quiz"></div>
<button id="submit">Get Results</button>
<p id="results"></p>
<button id="generate">Generate</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the updated code and the explanations, It worked perfectly, I had a few errors alright :-)